# Allauth signup template with normal and social account on one page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-authentication

I find the allauth templates a bit hard to understand and can't really figure out how I'd be able to create a template that allows to choose between social auth (FB in my case) and normal auth (email, etc.), like the one on Stackoverflow for example.

Basically I want to use the `{{ form.as_p }}` using the signup view.

Answer (score 2):

You could override [this](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/login.html) template (`account/login.html`).

For the normal login form, you can have the following snippet, extracted from the mentioned template:

```
{% load i18n %}
<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
  <button class="primaryAction" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
</form>
```

And for the facebook social authentication you can have the following, based on [this template](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html):

```
{% load socialaccount %} 
<a title="Facebook" class="socialaccount_provider facebook" 
     href="{% provider_login_url facebook process='login' %}">Facebook</a>
```

Both mentioned templates are provided by django-allauth, but can be overridden by adding a `templates` folder to your django app, and creating the same directory structure, in this case:

```
myapp
  |_templates
        |_account
             |_login.html
```

and putting your code in `login.html`. The same applies to any other template you want to override. [Here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates) are the templates of `django-allauth`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a form for the user/password for the "normal auth" and then add links for the social auth pages.

```
<form>
 user... pass...
</form>
<a href="">Facebook</a>
```